# c++ std::enable_if constraint variants and problems

Tags: c++, class, enums, c++14, enable-if

Just a short question given a function where I want to return the underlying type of an `enum class` :

Why does this version work fine

```
template<typename T>
constexpr inline
typename std::enable_if_t<
  std::is_enum<T>::value,
  typename std::underlying_type_t<T>
>
enumValue(T p_rVal) noexcept
{
  return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type_t<T>>(p_rVal);
}

if (enumValue(myEnumClass) == 0) {}
```

whereas this one fails with a "*no matching overloaded function found*" (VS 2015) error:

```
template<
  typename T,
  typename std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_enum<T>::value,
    typename std::underlying_type_t<T>
  >
>
constexpr inline
typename std::underlying_type_t<T>
enumValue(T p_rVal) noexcept
{
  return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type_t<T>>(p_rVal);
}
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: @Dan Why did you reject the proposed edit by 
Torbjörn? It makes perfect sense to improve the formatting of this post.

Comment: You don't need `typename` before `std::underlying_type_t<T>`.

Comment: Yep, right, C++14 advantage. I already removed them btw, but nevertheless thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, there is only one `template` parameter, `T`, which in the function call `enumValue(myEnumClass)` is deduced from the argument. This is the correct usage of `std::enable_if_t<>`.

In your second example, there are two`template` parameters and the first can again be deduced but not the second. This is an inappropriate/wrong way to use `std::enable_if_t<>`.

Comment: AH! Right, I tried, for the second version, template <t = std::enable_if<...>> and this works fine! Thanks for the (now accepted) answer!

Comment: Yup, default template argument is the way to go here. It doesn't clutter the function signature, and allows the use of `auto` return type deduction.